# HTML: Position element by the center of sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-float, vertical-alignment

Sorry for a dump question. I have never work with HTML.
I have following UI:

[image]

I would like to be `Success` centralized by the middle of `sendMessage` element.

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
      <div style="position: relative; width: 40%; float: left; vertical-align:middle">
            <button class="btn btn-default">sendMessage</button>
      </div>
      <div style="position: relative; width: 40%; float: right; vertical-align:middle">
            <span class="label label-success" style="font-size: small;">Success</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block` with `vertical-align: middle` like that:

```css
.send-button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

.success-info {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #9b8;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="send-button">Send Message</button>
  <div class="success-info">Success!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, they're two different divs, in a larger div. Both divs are being aligned according the larger div.

If you want to put those divs 'over' eachother, you'd have to use `position:relative` with an addition like: `left 100px`, in order to move the top div over the lower div (you may have to use a Z-index as well, in order to get the correct div on top).

Alternatively, it might work to place the 'success' div inside the 'button div'. If you then display the button as `display:flex`, and align the 'success div' to the center, it should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Its easier to use `inline-block`s instead of floating the divs. Try something like this:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box:before{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  
  }
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">
    <button id="resetCache" class="btn btn-default">sendMessage</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span id="resetCacheResponse" class="label label-success" style="font-size: small;">message</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve with only add

```
display: inline-block;
```

in same style code which you use

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Because without setting display your code not work properly.